# What happens if the main battery gets connected backwards?

Tags: electrical, battery, alternator, mitsubishi

2008 Mitsubishi Nativa (Pajero?) now no power coming from alternator after my experienced mechanic hooked up the car's battery backwards.

He saw the spark he said but didn't register as he was distracted, and ran the motor.

What has been damaged? Blown fuse(s)? Other damages?

I installed a known-good new battery, and connected it correctly.

The car will run but if battery wire is removed while running, then motor dies. I did this to check the alternator.   I am trying to resolve this issue myself.

Comment: Testing the alternator by disconnecting the battery can damage the alternator. Only test alternators correctly with suitable meters.

Comment: Can’t actually see what the question is.

Comment: What to check to determine why alternator not putting out voltage. Just looking for a heads up on what not to do. I checked fuse in the fuse box. Good. Large fuses connected to battery I cannot figure out how to remove. I understand they are bolted fuses but how to access the bolts for testing?

Comment: How do you know that the alternator is not providing current?

Comment: If you don’t have any test equipment, with the engine running, turn on your headlights, then turn the engine off. If the headlights dim slightly it would indicate that the alternator was powering them while the engine was running.

Comment: Thanks. When I get back to where the car is located (remote area) will give this a try. Plus this next time I will have a meter with me as well as some other equipment to try and sort this out.

Comment: Also, if you have a multimeter, you can check the voltage at the battery with the engine running. With a good alternator, it should be reading between 13.5-14.1vdc. If the alternator is bad, you'll only have battery voltage, and while running the voltage will slowly drop as more and  more power is consumed by the engine running.

Comment: Thank you. Next trip to the vehicle will have a multimeter with me.